# What's a const variable inside?

Tags: c++, c, constants, point

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  const int a=1;
  printf("a's address is %p\r\n",&a);
  printf("input a's address\r\n");
  int *p=NULL;
  //here let p point to a;
  scanf("%p",&p);
  printf("p point to  %p\r\n",p);
  *p=100;
  // I suppose a will be 100, but acturlly a is still 1...
  printf("a's value is %d\r\n",a);
  printf("*p's value is %d\r\n",*p);

  return 0;
}
```

Why is `a` still `1` and not `100`?

But if I declare `a` as:

```
int a =1;
```

It works!

So, how it goes?

Comment: In C (presumably it's the same in C++, but I don't know that language), it is **Undefined Behaviour** to (try and) change the value of a `const` qualified object. Anything can happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several places in your code where you invoke undefined behavior, which means anything can happen. `a` can be `1`, `100` or `"puppy"`.

First off, you can't do

```
scanf("%p",&p);
printf("p point to  %p\r\n",p);
*p=100;
```

because you probably don't own that memory. Even if you did, writing to it might be illegal. As-is the case here.

If you do this (change the value at `a`'s address) or used `const_cast` and then try to modify `a`, there'a another instance of undefined behavior. You made a promise `a` is `const` - don't change it.

The result is UB and the behavior probably happens because the compiler optimizes the `printf("a's value is %d\r\n",a);` to a simple `printf("a's value is %d\r\n",1);`, since it trusts you that you won't modify `a` (shame on him).

Answer (score 0):

When you declare `a` as `const`, the compiler is free to assume that it cannot ever change.  That you synthesize a pointer to it and try to modify it doesn't matter, because (apparently) your compiler has optimized away the actual loading of `a` when it is `const`.

Answer (score 0):

The `const` keyword specifies that a variable's value is constant and tells the compiler to prevent the programmer from modifying it.